# In Android, how can I reduce the the padding around the spinner's selected item?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, nine-patch

I've seared SO and have seen anything that really answered this for me.

I have a spinner:

[image]

I need to reduce the padding at the yellow highlighted areas. I've tried `android:padding="0dp"` and using `spinner.setPadding(...)` on my spinner in the java file when I add content to the spinner. Neither work.

I've read that I need to target the TextView inside the spinner but I'm not sure how to go about that.

The image used to create the border and arrow is already a 9.patch. The black lines show how I set it up.

[image]

I've updated the 9.patch. Still having the same issue:

[image]

Comment: You could probably fix this by changing your 9 patch.

Comment: there is a padding embedded in 9-patches by default. you can overcome it by defining explicitly your content area, using the right and bottom borders.

Comment: I've updated the 9 patch to define the fill area but still getting that extra padding. Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: have you found out how to solve this problem? I'm facing with it just now..